# Laravel cache a query the includes Auth::id()

Tags: php, laravel, caching, relationship

I have a Laravel application where all users credentials are stored in `users` table.

And I have multiple user roles, for each role there is a table in DB (admins, customers, ...) each one has different data.

I'm using `Auth::user()` multiple times in my application, and the query is executed only once on DB (as expected).

Example:

```php
$user1 = Auth::user();
$user2 = Auth::user();
$user3 = Auth::user();
$user4 = Auth::user();

// The query is executed only once in DB.
```

When I'm trying to access admin data using `Admin::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first()` multiple queries are executed.

Example:

```php
$user1 = Admin::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
$user2 = Admin::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
$user3 = Admin::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
$user4 = Admin::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();

// 4 queries are executed.
```

I have tried to add a relationship to user model as follows:

```php
// App\Models\User
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ...

    public function admin()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Admin::class, 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

When executing `Auth::user()->admin()` also 4 queries are executed.

I'm facing this problem in the model. I have this example model, where I need the agent to add an attribute:

```php
// App\Models\Card

...
public function getCurrencyAttribute() {
    $user = Auth::user() // This query is executed only once for all rows.
    $admin = Admin::where('user_id', Auth::id()); // This query is executed for each row (if I have 100 rows, it's executed 100 times).
    ...
}
...
```

Is there a way to cache the query as Auth::user() is cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, `Auth::user()` is not cached, it's just stored in memory,
and whenever you say `Model::where('condition')->first()`, you are telling the application to execute a query, so it will be executed, also when you say `Auth::user()->admin()`, you are calling it as a method, so it will return a query builder, you should call it as a property `Auth::user()->admin`, like this

try using `load` method, `Auth::user()->load(['admin'])`, it should append `admin` object to the user object.

good luck ✌